# many indexes for mongodb refined searches

Tags: performance, mongodb, indexing

Referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416402/badoo-com-user-search-how-can-this-be-done) question here:

I am working on a similar site using mongodb as my main database. As you can imagine, each user object has a lot of fields that need to be serchable, say for example mood, city, age, sex, smoker, drinker, etc.

Now, apart from the problem that there cannot be more than 64 indexes per collection, is it wise to assign index to all of my fields?

There might be another viable way of doing it: tags (refer to [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869125/mongodb-many-indexes-vs-single-index-on-array-of-sub-documents) question) If i set the index on an array of predetermined tags and then text-search over them, would it be better? as I am using only ONE index. What do you think? E.g.:

```
{
   name: "john",
   tags: ["happy", "new-york", "smoke0", "drink1"]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB [doesn't (yet) support index intersection](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3071), so the rule is: one index per query. Some of your query parameters have extremely low selectivity, the extreme example being the boolean ones, and indexing those will usually slow things down rather than speed them up.

As a simple approximation, you could create a compound index that starts with the highest-selectivity fields, for instance {"city", "age", "mood", ... }. However, then you will always have to use a city constraint. If you query for {age, mood}, the above index wouldn't be used.

If you can narrow down your result set to a reasonable size using indexes, a scan within that set won't be a performance hog. More precisely, if you say `limit(100)` and MongoDB has to scan 200 items to fill up those 100, it won't be critical.

The danger lies is very narrow searches across the database - if you have to perform a scan on the entire dataset to find the only unhappy, drinking non-smoker older than 95, things get ugly.

If you want to allow very fine grained searches, a dedicated search database such as SolR might be a better option.

EDIT: The `tags` suggestion looks a bit like using the crowbar to me -- maybe the [key/value multikey index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/indexes/#how-can-i-effectively-use-indexes-strategy-for-attribute-lookups) recommended by in the MongoDB FAQ is a cleaner solution:

```
{ _id : ObjectId(...),
  attrib : [
            { k: "mood", v: "happy" },
            { k: "city": v: "new york" },
            { k: "smoker": v: false },
            { k: "drinker": v: true }
           ]
}
```

However, YMMV and 'clean' and 'fast' often don't point in the same direction, so the `tags` approach might not be bad at all.

Comment: does solr work with mongodb, as well? also, have a look at the edit :)

Comment: SolR is a separate database, but it can make sense to search SolR for a list of IDs of users and store the actual data in MongoDB. For one thing, the data in your actual database cannot be recreated while search indexes can. Also, search indexes might have to be rebuilt and while it might not be cool if your search is down or incomplete, it's usually much worse if your primary DB is down.

Comment: @mnemosyn Index Intersection is available now. Maybe you can post an update.

Comment: @AjayGeorge: For this particular implementation of this use case, the upcoming implementation of index intersection will help automatically because of the self-intersection in the array. However, the upcoming index intersection can't replace this array-based approach very well because it is limited to two indices, so the new rule is: at most two indices per query or 10 self-intersections. So, if you're unlucky, two indexes only get you from 1M potential hits to 10k potential hits which is a lot to scan. So the array approach is still better.